# How to check if an event was raised or not within a particular time frame?

Tags: .net, multithreading, events, c++-cli

I am coding an application using C++CLI on .Net4.0 I have an event handler for an event that can be raised at any random time
The event is usefull only if it happens within a particular time frame (or it should occur once in a time period)
I need to check if the event was raised once in the past interval or not. If it was not raised in  a particular time interval i will raise an exception.

I have tried implementing it like this:

1. Add a boolean flag variable to the class
2. IN the event handler, set
   the flag = true
3. To do the checking I have a timer event:
4. The timer event is raised evey 200 ms
5. It checks if the flag is true
6. if it is
   true it sets a counter to 0
7. Timer event then sets the flag to false
8. if it finds that the flag is false it increments a counter
9. if the counter has reached a limit (say three) then it throws an exception.

However I found that it gives false positives. Thios probably happens because the event is being blocked or something?

Does anybody know a better way to do it? i would like to know if there is some way to do it without an external timer event (or thread) as it may interrupt other threads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if my comment can help you, but did you try to make the event handler to create an object of `static` checker class with `static` flag on constructor? Each object creating process will increment the static flag. Then you can compare between the value of the flag and the time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the implications of your c++CLI, but when I unit test async events in C# I usually do this:

```
    [Test]
    public void CheckThatEventIsRaisedWithinTimeframe()
    {
        var eventRaised = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        subject.SomeEvent += (s, e) => { eventRaised.Set(); };

        // Do something which should have triggered the event

        Assert.True(eventRaised.WaitOne(5000), "Event was not raised.");
    }
```

The WaitOne call will block until either the time runs out (in this case 5 seconds), or the event is raised. In the first case WaitOne will return false, and in the second case it'll return true.

I assume you could do something similar, for example:

```
var eventRaised = new AutoResetEvent(false);
subject.SomeEvent += (s, e) => { eventRaised.Set(); };

while(true)
{
    var ok = eventRaised.WaitOne(5000);
    if(!ok)
         throw new Exception("Event was not raised for 5 seconds");
}
```

This should keep running and throw an exception if the event isn't raised at least every 5 seconds.